# Can't Reset Display Settings

Tags: multiple-monitors, external-display

I'm on Windows 10. Sometimes I connect my tv to my desktop to watch shows online from my couch. I connected the hdmi to my desktop and the screen was mirroring, but nothing was displaying on the tv. When I was trying to troubleshoot, I hit show on monitor 2 and the visual moved from my main monitor to my tv, which is still blank. So whenever I connect to my tv, I lose all visuals. I can only reset this setting when the hdmi is plugged in, but then I can't see.

How can I reset all the display settings, so I can troubleshoot the original problem lol?

Answer (score 1):

Try doing a graphics driver reboot

```
Win+CTRL+Shift+b
```

- Uninstall drivers, and see if the Windows drivers works better. Or vice versa.
- Swap HDMI cables. Some HDTV have an HDMI/DVI port, use that one.
- Try to set desktop monitor to the same resolution as your TV. If 1080 doesn't work, try 720p resolution on both displays.

Comment: So after messing with it for a while. Restarting and resetting display settings I gave up and a couple days later it was working again. Idk lol